# Why am I geting "Disk validation failed [Invalid S3 source location]" while doing "aws ec2 import-image"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to import a VM to ec2.
My containers.json file

```
[
 {
   "Description": "Cloudera task",
   "Format": "ova",
   "UserBucket": {
    "S3Bucket": "cdh-5.5.0.0-sandbox",
    "S3Key": "cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.5.0-0-virtualbox.ova"
    }
 }
]
```

And my command is :

```
aws ec2 import-image --description "Cloudera Sandbox" --disk-containers file://containers-cdh.json
```

However, my import task is failing with

```
"StatusMessage": "ClientError: Disk validation failed [Invalid S3 source location]"
```

- The s3 bucket and my default CLI settings are in the same location.
- The ova file was uploaded to the s3 bucket.
- S3Key is the filename of the .ova file in the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error can be due to the invalid s3 bucket name. s3 bucket names should not have hyphens.

Comment: Thanks! How did you figure that out :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the bucket name is correct? Does the bucket exist? Can you run the CLI command
**`aws s3 ls s3://cdh-5.5.0.0-sandbox`** ? It will give you a clue.

[Invalid S3 source location](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportTroubleshooting.html#InvalidS3SourceLocation)

The command syntax or Amazon S3 bucket name is incorrect.

**Resolution**

Create a new Amazon S3 bucket in the appropriate region solely for VM Import and upload the VM files to the root of the bucket.

Comment: It was a bucket name problem. Generally - and . are allowed in bucket names, but it didn't seem to work in this case. Using "cdhsandbox" as the bucket name worked.